# How do I get hundreds of DLL files?

Tags: python, dll, gdal

I am using python and I am trying to install the GDAL library. I kept having an error telling me that many DLL files were missing so I used the software Dependency Walker and it showed me that 330 DLL files were missing...

My question is: How do I get that much files without downloading them one by one on a website ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, never download `.dll` files from shady websites.

The best way of repairing missing dependencies is to reinstall the software that shipped the `.dll` files completely.

Answer (score 1):

By properly installing the software that GDAL depends on.

Consult GDAL's documentation for build and installation instructions.